# How to resolve SessionNotCreatedException for selenium:chromedriver using Robotframework?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I had recently upgraded the selenium version for my Robotframework project and ever since I see that chrome driver tries to open the chrome browser but fails to initials with the error

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

System details :
    Chrome browser version: 76.0.3809.132
    Windows 10 machine
    chromedriver location : C:\Python27

How does the chrome look like when error occurs ?
 [image]

Occurrence: The issue happens 1 out of 4 test cases in a suite always. The chrome browser opens for 600 seconds and gets closed. It looks like the screen is trying to initials the browser.

```
Troubleshoot :
           1. Tried downloading the latest chrome driver 76.0.3809.132
           2. Tried cleaning the project and rerun
           3. Restarted the system
           4. Tried creating a fresh project.
           5. Tried running using from eclipse, pybot,  robot
           6. Updated all the libraries found in pip freeze.   Python 2.7.9 version used
           7. Was it working with previous version of Selenium and chrome driver 76.0.3809.132 with chrome browser 76.0.3809.132? BIG YES, but now I don't know what version I was using.
           8. Tried using selenium grid docker container and the script ran successfully.
```

Code used :

```
*** Settings ***

Library    SeleniumLibrary 
*** Keywords ***

Open Browser local
    [Arguments]    ${URL}  
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}

*** Test Cases ***

TC1
   [Setup]  Open Browser local    ${URL}
    #Maximize Browser Window
    Set Browser Implicit Wait    10s  
    Input Text    id=loginid    xxx
    Click Button    id=continue-button    
    Input Text    id=login-password    xxx

    Click Button    id=login-button    
    Sleep    10s  
    [Teardown]   Close Browser
```

Libraries installed : 
[image]

[image]

Question : 
           Please let me know how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, any suggestion on this, please

Comment: Check for network restrictions on the driver, from Windows' Firewall (or any other firewall you may be using).

Comment: @TodorMinakov, as mentioned in the analysis, the error is thrown 1 out of 4 times

Comment: Does it happen exactly 1 of 4 times ? Exactly same tests pass and same tests fail ? Are your other Test Teardowns different ?

Comment: @BrianO'Neill, the failure happens randomly and not always the same test cases fail, some times all test cases fail, sometimes one or two out of four fails. It is unpredictable which one fails. All test cases are having the same line of code and setup , teardown.

Comment: Hi all, Finally I was able to find the issue here , I am using JayDeBeApi for database connection and the library JPype1- version 7 that gets deployed along was causing the issue, Tried downgrading it to JPype1 0.6.3 but still the problem persist. I had to reinstall Python and reinstalled all with robot execpt JayDeBeApi and it has started working.